# Unable to add a ribbon button to a custom list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Edit: Updated with input from Omlin

I am attempting to add a custom button to the ribbon.  I want the button associated with a custom list named “Products”.  I am able to get the button to show for a built-in list, such as a Shared Documents, but not the custom products list.

Below are examples of my code working with an existing list and not working with the custom list.  I’ve also attached links to the working and non-working code that create the custom list and the ribbon button.  These solutions assume that you have a site created at http://intranet.contoso.com.  You will probably need to change Site URL of the project to get the code to run.

---

### Working with and built-in list (Shared Documents):

**Elements XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
       <CustomAction
              Id="CustomRibbonTab"
              Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
              RegistrationId="101"
              RegistrationType="List"
              Title="My Custom UI"
              Sequence="5"
              >
              <CommandUIExtension>
                     <CommandUIDefinitions>
                           <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children">
                                  <Button
                                         Id="Ribbon.Items.New.RibbonTest"
                                         Alt="Test Button"
                                         Sequence="5"
                                         Command="Test_Button"
                                         LabelText="Click me!"
                                         Image32by32="/_layouts/images/ribbon_blog_32.png"
                                         Image16by16="/_layouts/images/ribbon_blog_16.png"
                                         TemplateAlias="o1"
                                         />
                           </CommandUIDefinition>
                     </CommandUIDefinitions>
                     <CommandUIHandlers>
                           <CommandUIHandler Command="Test_Button"
                                                         CommandAction="javascript:alert('I am a test!');">

                           </CommandUIHandler>
                     </CommandUIHandlers>
              </CommandUIExtension>
       </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

**Working Example**
[image: Working Example]

**Full Visual Studio Solution**:
http://employees.claritycon.com/pwalke/blogs/working.zip

---

### Not Working

**Elements XML**:  I changed 2 lines from the above code.
Line 28: Associate the button with the custom products list, ID 10001, specified in the list template of the zipped code below.

```
RegistrationId="10001"
```

Line 85: Tell SharePoint to place the item within the Items menu.

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children">
```

**Screenshot** – I would have expected the custom ribbon button to be added to the left of New Item.
[image: Not Working]

**Full Visual Studio Solution**:
http://employees.claritycon.com/pwalke/blogs/notworking.zip

Comment: +1 Very clear and detailed explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.  Thanks to omlin for getting me part of the way there.

This was a 2-part issue.

1:
 As suggested by omlin, I changed

```
Ribbon.Items.New.Controls._children
```

to

```
Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children
```

2: I had to change the schema.xml's toolbar declarations from

```
<ToolBar />
```

to

```
<Toolbar Type="Regular"/>
```

Comment: in my solution Toolbar.Type values do not have value "Regular". which toolbar node nis it and in which schema.xml?

Answer (score 7):

> Ribbon.Items.New.Controls._children

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx), simply there is no such Ribbon location :)

I don't have SharePoint here right now to test, but I feel you need use **Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children**

---

Update: So far, I tested the button adding to Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children. It works fine for me (I haven't use any registration type & registration id yet). Sample code I used is:

```
  <CustomAction
  Id="ChangeBrowseTabTitle"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
          Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.ListItem.New.RibbonTest"
            Alt="Test Button"
            Sequence="5"
            Command="Test_Button"
            LabelText="Click me!"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/SharePointTestProject/avatar32.png"
            TemplateAlias="o1"
              />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="Test_Button" CommandAction="javascript:alert('I am a test!');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

The result is:

[image]

So I will try to test the custom list binging now.

---

Update: I took your "notworking.zip" project, and tried the code. With no luck.
But when I created blank new list definition (Solution -> right-click -> Add -> New Item -> List Definition from content type), assigned custom id to it (10012), and changed reference in ribbon, it started working:

[image]

---

**Final result**

So something was wrong with your list definition, actually. I don't have enough time to check all the xml, so simply I created new list with same columns as I described above, deleted your old one, and all is working now. You can download the final solution, using this link:

https://sites.google.com/site/omlinfiles/StackOverflow.RibbonCustomList.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

P.S. don't forget to change Site URL

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read my issue and the  the quick reply.  I updated the code with those changes, but the ribbon button still does not show up on the custom list.  I've looked at the ribbon xml definition in the 14 hive along with trying to debug the issue with firebug, but still no dice.  Any further input is much much appreciated.

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache? (In IE - F12, menu Cache -> Always update from server). Anyway, I'll try to test the issue tomorrow morning (GMT+3) on my SharePoint environment.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll try this later today and let you know the results.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a ribbon button to a custom list, wich had been created through Site Actions Menu interface without feature on vs2010, you can do it setting the attribute RegistrationId to **100** (generic list).

Example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="ListFolderSecurityButton"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="100"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
         Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children">
          <Button
           Id="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls.ListFolderSecurity"
           Alt="Gestiona los permisos de acceso de lectores en el folder"
           Sequence="10"
           Image32by32="/_layouts/images/Permissions32.png"
           Command="ManageSecurityFolder"
           LabelText="Folder Permissions"
           TemplateAlias="o2"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
         Command="ManageSecurityFolder"
         CommandAction="/CustomPages/PMS_AdminSecurityFolder.aspx" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
  <!--<HideCustomAction Id="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls.ListFolderSecurityButton" Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children">
  </HideCustomAction>-->
</Elements>
```